# KineticJS Text RTLing

Tags: kineticjs, right-to-left

So I've been using KineticJS for a project which envolves writing text in Hebrew, and I realized that the text I'm writing is being aligned left-to-right and not right-to-left - although my body tag contains dir="rtl" and the CSS for my container div includes "direction: rtl". I have researched the topic and couldn't find anything, so I came here for help. Does anybody here know how to make Kinetic.Text that will be RTL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic RTL for Kinetic.Text, but you can do this workaround:

```
var a=rtl("0123456789");

function rtl(a){
    return(a.slice(-1)+a.slice(0,a.length-1));
}
```

Example Kinetic.Text:

```
var theText="Hello, World!";

var simpleText = new Kinetic.Text({
  x: 20,
  y: 16,
  text: rtl(theText),
  fontSize: 12,
  fontFamily: 'Hebrew David',
  fill: 'black'
});
```

Comment: Okay, can't believe I didn't notice it before, but this doesn't really RTL the text. It does move punctuation to the left, but it also reverses the whole text - i.e. if I type "hello", it will display "olleh". How can I fix it so only the punctuation will switch sides?

Comment: My bad...I have reread your question and edited my answer with a solution.  Again, sorry!

Comment: It's okay haha, no worries. Since then I have already made a function for "manual RTLing" based on your answer. I have also opened an [issue](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/issues/858) in the KineticJS GitHub, asking for a Kinetic.Text "dir" property. Thanks for your help!